# Objective Cconvert id(type) to NSNumber:Error

Tags: objective-c, casting

i want to convert id* to NSNumber *

trying this 
`unsigned int ShortValue  = [(NSNumber *)idObject unsignedShortValue];`

but this aint compiling

`Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with ARC`

any ideas how to do it.
basically id* object will be argument to my method ,second argument will be type information of this id* object then inside this method i am  performing type specific methods on it like one above

Comment: Could you show us the code for how you create `idObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is a semi-primitive type, as it is declared in objc.h as

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

When you create id objects, you don't use an "*", as that is for pointers to objects, so basically don't do this:

```
id *someObject;
```

The correct syntax would be this:

```
id someObject;
```

Hope this helps!

--------EDIT------ 
I tried out the code you used:

```
unsigned int ShortValue = [(NSNumber *)idObject unsignedShortValue];
```

and it compiled fine. I think the error is how you create `idObject`.

---------EDIT---------

Here's an apple doc on `id`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html 
and here's two good resources on the `isa` pointer: [What does isa mean in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405224/what-does-isa-mean-in-objective-c), http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html. In the second link, scroll to the top third of the article to find info on `isa*`. Hope this helps!

Comment: :D  I meant please provide the correct syntax for the OP's expression!

Comment: @qegal ohh wow that was a subtle thing! thanks a dozen it works now!!
could you provide documentation which will tell me inner workings of these things like isa* and id and relevant things.