# Null in the output

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone explain why `self.mathFunc.text = null` in the output ? 
Code:

```
-(id) initWithValue:(NSString *) value {
    self = [self init];
    NSLog(@"value %@",value);
    self.mathfunc.text  = value;
    NSLog(@"self.mathFunc.text %@",self.mathfunc.text);
    [self setLabel];
    return self;
}
```

and output is

```
014-01-10 15:18:09.566 MathRacer[1573:a0b] value Div
2014-01-10 15:18:09.568 MathRacer[1573:a0b] self.mathFunc.text (null)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess `self.mathfunc` is null, and because of that you cannot assign something to its property.

edit:

you are trying to set an IBOutlet's Property in the initialisation, but there's no UI at this time. You'll have to move this code to `- (void)viewDidLoad`, then the `IBOutlets` are assigned.

Comment: can you give any solution for this?

Comment: i don't know wich type `mathfunc` is, you have to create an object for this property first, before you can assign something to it.

Comment: '@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mathfunc;'

Answer (score 2):

You must allocate `self.mathFunc` before assign any value to it. When you call `initWithValue` method the self class create with some default values if values are primitive then it get scalar values or if class containing reference type objects then by default it generate as (null). 
You can see if you place break point on 1st line of `initWithValue` method then in print description of `isa` pointer you will get all scenario.

See this link will helpful you :- [What does isa mean in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405224/what-does-isa-mean-in-objective-c)