# Why do I have an object with an address of `0x30000000`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

What do I have an object that has the distinctly odd address of `0x30000000`?

E.g.

[image: isa = (Class)0x30000000]

It looks similar to what I'd get for a nil object.

Comment: Err, no, as `nil` would be `0x0`.  What's the issue? I can find little reference to `0x30000000` as being special, other than "Further, addresses over 0x30000000 are reserved for the various libraries
and frameworks" from "Mac OS X and iOS Internals".

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405224/what-does-isa-mean-in-objective-c.

Comment: If the code is working as expected, then that'd mean that the NSData's objc_class struct happens to be mapped into memory at exactly 0x300....0.    Either that or something pooped a very round number on that bit of memory.   As @trojanfoe indicates, that address is the beginning of system space and, thus, it may likely be where the Foundation dylib was mapped.   You could grub about with the mach-o APIs to find out more, if available.

Comment: @bbum I did have a dig around in the [objc-private.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-680/runtime/objc-private.h) that you publish, and the only thing of interest was `SUPPORT_NONPOINTER_ISA` which is for 64-bit only and doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yeah-- you aren't going to find it there.   You'd have to poke about on the device itself, of which there are limited options to do so.  I *think* the mach APIs are available and one could walk the shared library list.  Maybe.   Or maybe NSBundle/CFBundle has an option?  In any case, that NSData would fall exactly at that address seems very odd.  Looking at a couple of vmmaps, I don't see anything lining up quite like that.  I be baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally Objective-C classes are represented by C `struct`s, "understood" by Objective-C runtime. One of the members in `NSObject`'s `struct` is a pointer of type `Class`, called `isa`. It is used to retrieve information about the methods of the class, its inheritance structure, and so on.

You are looking at the `NSData` object, which derives from `NSObject`. Its `isa` pointer happens to point at the address `0x30000000`.

Comment: You think it *happens* to be `0x30000000`?

Comment: @trojanfoe The address does look rather round, so I suspect it may have been written over, perhaps after having been released.

Comment: I believe it's special, but have nothing other than instinct to back that up :)  I am unsure if the question is about `isa` or `0x30000000` though.

Comment: But then the OP has asked the wrong question. If he's crashing with a deallocated object he should ask about _that_.

Comment: @matt This looks like output of the debugger, so perhaps his code has not crashed at the point when he has examined the object.